# How intercompatible are B/X and AD&D 1e spells?

Tags: spells, balance, adnd-1e, conversion, dnd-bx

What balance issues would/could arise if AD&D spells are transferred into a B/X game?

I'm only considering those spells which don't already exist in B/X and I'm not considering adding in the higher level spells from AD&D.  I am thinking about things like, for example, Faerie Fire; ported over without any change (same level, range, area of effect and so on).

Comment: An anecdote from decades ago; I played the B/X games with friends and we picked up the AD&D player's manual and started using that for the characters.  I don't recall any issues, but it was a very long time ago and mostly dealt with lower levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It appears that they would be generally compatible.

**Sources**

- Basic Rules Set
- Expert Rules Set
- AD&D 1e. Player's Handbook
- AC11 - The Book of Wondrous Inventions

From examining a few low-level spells, as you suggested that is what you were primarily interested in, it appears that the spells are generally comparable in effect, with some variation.

I'm using the scaling of 1" = 10', as this is what is used in AC11 (see below for more information). D&D didn't really assume miniatures, and AD&D scaling is only designed for tabletop inches, so area variations are probably minor.

| Spell | D&D | AD&D | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cure Light Wounds | Heals 1d6+1 hp | Heals 1d8 hp | Avg 4.5 in both |
| Light | Lights a 30' diameter | Lights a 4" diameter | 4" = 40'; AD&D is a bit larger |
| Magic Missile | 1d6+1 damage +2 darts per 5 lvls | 1d4+1 damage +1 dart per 2lvls | AD&D has slightly lower damage, but adds darts slightly earlier |
| Sleep | Affects 2d8 HD | Affects 4d4 1HD creatures | AD&D shifts the avg. up and handles creatures with >1HD in a more complicated way |
| Web | Affects a 10'x10'x10' cube | Affects an area totaling 2"x2"x2" | 2"=20'; AD&D has a larger area and lets you shape it within reason. |
| Fireball | 1d6 damager per level, 20' radius | 1d6 damage per level, 2" radius | 2"=20'; same area. |
| Lightning Bolt | 1d6 damager per level, 5' width, 60' length | 1d6 damage per level, 1" wide 4" long or 0.5" wide 8" long | At 1"=10' the AD&D bolt is 20' shorter and twice as wide or 20' longer. |

***AC11 - The Book of Wondrous Inventions*** describes a series of (often silly) magical items, complete with creation rules. These items are expected to be compatible with both games.

> The material included in this product is for use with both the DUNGEONS &
> DRAGONS Game and the ADVANCED DUNGEONS & DRAGONS Game.

The book also provided spell-creation rules for the D&D game. This implies the idea of introducing new spells to the game is already in place, and that spells designed for one game would be generally compatible with the other.

> ##### Creating Spells and Magical Items
>
> The guidelines suggested below are designed to function especially for the
> D&D Game. For the AD&D Game, refer to the DMG. AD&D Dungeon Masters may use the system suggested below, adding appropriate modifications whenever needed for AD&D rules.

The spell creation rules assume a certain amount of DM review, but it looks like most spells would not cause major problems if moved from one system to the other.